# Issue with Query execution with different versions of Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: vb.net, oracle, dll, asmx

I have an asmx service deployed on the server which is using Oracle.DataAccess.dll (2.112.4.0). The application runs several complex queries on the Oracle database and runs fine. 
I am suppose to migrate this application to support a latter version of the oracle client. Currently I'm trying to achieve this using Oracle 11g client installed on my machine having Oracle.DataAccess.dll (4.112.3.0).
But while executing any queries, I'm getting the error :

> Failed to load DataSet ORA-01036: illegal variable name/number

The query I'm trying to execute contains certain parameters which are being added to the query that is something like, `userId = @UserId` (which is a string ,"abc").

When I tried to execute the same query with hard coded parameters, it runs fine.
My hard coded query is something like:

```
Select * from tabl1 where userId = 'abc' and systemId = 3
```

I am suspecting the issue to be with the difference in the data types due to the different dll versions. But even after using the older version of the dll in my code, I'm getting the same error.

Any help with this will be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to use the parameter marker `:` instead of `@`?

Comment: Thanks Steve, using your suggestion, i was able to track down the issue to the actual query that was being generated. I figured out that the actual query being generated was supposed to have ":" instead of "@" which was causing the ORA-01036 error. This was due to some issue with how the connection string is being generated from the config file.